# How to change a glyphicons text in javascript

Tags: javascript, glyphicons, linkbutton

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-default search" runat="server" ID="ShowHide" 
OnClientClick="return false;" title="Hide Search"><span id="glyphBtn" 
class="glyphicons glyphicons-plus"></span>Show Search Criteria</asp:LinkButton>

if (blnShowFilter == 'false') {
            document.getElementById('glyphBtn').className = 'glyphicons glyphicons-minus';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('glyphBtn').className = 'glyphicons glyphicons-plus';
        }
```

I have been able to change the actual glyphicon itself but I am struggling to get at the text inside the link button but outside the span. The text 'Show Search Criteria' I want this to change to 'Hide Search Criteria' when the button has been clicked, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (blnShowFilter == 'false') 
    document.getElementById('ShowHide').innerHTML = '<span id="glyphBtn" class="glyphicons glyphicons-minus"></span>Hide Search Criteria';
else 
    document.getElementById('ShowHide').innerHTML = '<span id="glyphBtn" class="glyphicons glyphicons-plus"></span>Show Search Criteria';
```

Instead of changing the class of `glyphicon` change the `innerHTML` of `#ShowHide` button with `updated text and new class` of `glyphicon`

Comment: You may need to use the client id with it being an asp link button

Comment: @Pete i couldn't understand. Please explain.

Comment: Depending on your settings, when an asp button gets rendered, the id sometimes changes to include a load of extra control information to make sure it is unique so `ShowHide` may not be the final id

Comment: @Pete oh okay, got you.

Comment: This is a much better way of doing it. In this instance it seems to be working without using ClientID, thank you.